# Using memcache in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, memcached, codeigniter-2

I need to have library that can be used as memcache with my codeigniter. what I need to do is to extract menus from DB on user's role basis and then store the menu in cache. The idea is to show the exact menu to another user if it has the same role(without calling DB). I have a separate view for menus(Header) and includes it on each of my page(view). Here a thing to note is every time a controller is executed when requesting to a new page(view).

I just used a library https://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library which did not work for me in this scenario. As I call the new page the header view throws an error for not defined get function for memcache (as I am getting data in header through memcache).

Is there any solid library or way to accomplish the task?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CodeIgniter2 has caching library, which supports Memcache https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#memcached-caching

Use something lilke that:

```
$role_id = 2;  
$menu = $foo = $this->cache->get('menu_'.$role_id);
if (!$menu){
  $menu_data = $this->my_model->loadMenu($role_id);
  $menu = $this->load->view('menu_tpl', $menu_data, TRUE);
  $this->cache->save('menu_'.$role_id, $menu);
}
```

Sample memcache.php from the [CI forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180005/#855216)

```
<?php
  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  $config['memcached'] = array(
          'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port'        => 11211,
          'weight'    => 1
  );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response AquilaX. Are these cached objects are globally accessible throughout the application?

Comment: Also I am not able to save the data in cache. while getting the data I am getting 'false'.

Comment: The code was just a sample. The objects are globally accessible cause they use the same server. Did you configure the caching correctly?

Comment: I just write the line $this->load->driver('cache'); and use it as you said. Actually I am new to codeigniter and don't know how to configure it :(

Comment: You must select the adapter first like that: $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'file')); Also you must setup the server in application/config/memcache.php

Comment: I am not able to get memcache.php from above location. Do i need to create it myself? How to configure it? I am using Codeigniter 2.0.3

Comment: Yes the memcache.php file is missing and you have to create it. I added a sample config in the answer.

Comment: how to assign a `$persistent_id` http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.construct.php incodeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

There is a forum post with the correct method outlined here:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180005/

Comment: Great example of why not to use link as primary answer :'(